# Strip URL - Python

Tags: python, regex, url, strip

Ok how do i use regex to remove http **AND/OR** www just to get **http://www.domain.com/** into **domain.com**

Assume x as any kind of TLD or cTLD

**Input example**:

http://www.domain.x/

www.domain.x

**Output**:

domain.x

Comment: **str.lstrip([chars])**
Return a copy of the string with leading characters removed. The chars argument is a string specifying the set of characters to be removed. If omitted or None, the chars argument defaults to removing whitespace. The chars argument is not a prefix; rather, all combinations of its values are stripped:

   ``>>> '   spacious   '.lstrip()``
   ``'spacious   '``
   ``>>> 'www.example.com'.lstrip('cmowz.')``
   ``'example.com' ``

Comment: It is worth mentioning that there are also www-pub, www-groups, www2, www3 and other www like prefixes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to use regular expressions instead of `urlparse()` or splitting the string:

```
>>> domain = 'http://www.example.com/'
>>> re.match(r'(?:\w*://)?(?:.*\.)?([a-zA-Z-1-9]*\.[a-zA-Z]{1,}).*', domain).groups()[0]
example.com
```

The regular expression might a bit simplistic, but works. It's also not replacing, but I think getting the domain out is easier.

To support domains like 'co.uk', one can do the following:

```
>>> p = re.compile(r'(?:\w*://)?(?:.*?\.)?(?:([a-zA-Z-1-9]*)\.)?([a-zA-Z-1-9]*\.[a-zA-Z]{1,}).*')
>>> p.match(domain).groups()
```

('google', 'co.uk')

So you got to check the result for domains like 'co.uk', and join the result again in such a case. Normal domains should work OK. I could not make it work when you have multiple subdomains.

One-liner without regular expressions or fancy modules:

```
>>> domain = 'http://www.example.com/'
>>> '.'.join(domain.replace('http://','').split('/')[0].split('.')[-2:])
```

Comment: I managed to paste the wrong regex in my initial post, but it's now edited with the correct one.

Comment: @Natsume Made me think, and I've updated the regex so 'http://' is optional and it accept any protocol, like 'https://' or 'bzr://'.

Comment: @Wooble I wouldn't say horribly, since it returns 'co.uk', but I understand the problem. I'm adding a solution for this.

Answer (score 7):

Don't use regex, use urlparse to get netloc

```
>>> x = 'http://www.domain.com/'
>>> from urlparse import urlparse
>>> o = urlparse(x)
>>> o
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='www.domain.com', path='/', params='', query='', fragment='')
>>>
```

and then

```
>>> o.netloc
'www.domain.com'
>>> if o.netloc.startswith('www.'): print o.netloc[4:]
... 
domain.com
>>>
```

Comment: `o.netloc.startswith('www.')` would be more appropriate than `'www' in o.netloc`

Comment: @Janne Karila: Thanks Janne. Lost that completely in quick answering. Thats ofcourse the correct way and not the one I presented. It is infact incorrect.

Comment: python 3.5 : from urllib.parse import urlparse

Answer (score 1):

Here is one of the way to do it:

```
    >>>import re
    >>>str1 = 'http://www.domain.x/'
    >>>p1 = re.compile('http://www.|/')
    >>>out = p1.sub('',str1)
```

Comment: Nice, but it does not cover where 'www' would be missing from the URL.

Comment: one can use match from re as below to check if required substring 'www' exists or not : >>> print p1.match("www")